# Selective copy cassandra million rows data to external file

Tags: cassandra, copy

I have tried copying cassandra table data to an external .dat file. For few rows it works fine.

```
echo "select * from <schema>.events limit 5000 ;" | /home.../bin/cqlsh > output.dat
```

But when I do the same for some millions of rows, it is taking time. Say, 5,00,000 rows takes 4 mins.

I have to do selective copy of data around 3,00,00,000 rows on incremental. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use COPY command to copy cassandra table data to some external file.

Comment: COPY works but not for this much of rows and also, it does not have selective options