# How to Copy Selective Rows from Cassandra Tables?

Tags: cassandra, copy, export-to-csv, nosql

I want to copy only selective rows and columns from a specific Cassandra table. How do I that?

I am able to copy complete tables in .csv format with the help of:https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html

But, how do I copy selective data only?

I tried referencing: [Selective copy cassandra million rows data to external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332538/selective-copy-cassandra-million-rows-data-to-external-file?s=1|3.7649) AND [Cassandra selective copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452158/cassandra-selective-copy?s=2|2.9423) . But none of them work.

Comment: cqlsh host port -u username -e "select column1, column2 from keyspace.tableName" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > 'path_to_file_where_you_want_to_copy_result' 

This command can be used to copy specific columns from a table(s) into a file. 
Note: If you have configured username and password to connect to cassandra, this command will prompt for password, give password to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for selective copy. You could either export the whole bunch of data and do filtering on the client side or use some 
Map-Reduce (or Spark) job otherwise to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which columns you would like to update. Say, if you 10 different columns but you want to copy only 3 of them then you specify like this

```
COPY products (name, id, color) from 'products.csv';
```

The only constraint over here is the CSV files should contain the only 3 columns.
I'd suggest you to make a copy of csv file and refactor it. You can easily do it in python using csv library.